# Generator.yml - problem with fields type: plain

Tags: symfony1

What's the problem here?

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           Builds
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          builds
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      fields:
        locality: {type: plain}
```

Field 'locality' is not a plain but it's show as an input tag! Why?? What's wrong?

Comment: locality:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately symfony does not have a readonly form widget out of the box. If you want such functionality, create a new form widget class that only renders a label and no input tag.

Comment: And if i want to write a select tag?

Comment: Yes but i have to do it in generator.yml (backend)

Comment: You should modify your forms via the form class, not in the generator.yml.